# Spring integration continuously monitor channel messages if they meet condition

Tags: spring, integration, message, monitor

I need to continuously monitor the messages in my channel and discover when they finally meet a certain criteria. To be exact: my messages in the channel hold info about a certain point in time. I need to know when 15 mins have passed from that point in time so that i either discard the messages or move them to another channel, based on some other info they contain. For this continuous monitoring and checking the deadline condition, what spring integration endpoint should i use? I thought about filters, but i don’t think they monitor continuously every message, they rather check for the condition only once per message.